# Using CSS3 to animate opacity with display:none

Tags: firefox, css, webkit, opacity, css-transitions

I have an element, with a child container which is initially hidden. When I hover over the parent, the child should be displayed. Simple.

Now, for real browsers, I want to add some flair and have the child fade in — while still keeping basic functionality for non-CSS3 compliant browsers. For old browsers, I simply toggle `display`, while I animate the `opacity` for all the kids with cool browsers. Should be a simple operation, right?

To my great surprise and disappointment, this is kind of buggy.

In **Firefox**, when I hover on, the child element switches to being fully opaque, before fading **out**. But hey, I want it to start as fully transparent, and then fade **in**!

In **Webkit**, the animation does not trigger — only the `display` toggle.

In **IE** (including IE10 PP) it also simply toggles `display` (as expected, though I had hoped it would animate in IE10).

In **Opera** everything works swell. <3 <3

Now, if I remove the `display:none;` from the initial declaration, the animation works beautifully in **Fx**, but then I will have problems with uncool browsers, which is sadly predominant among the visitors of this particular project.

Since I possess the powers of Modernizr, I can simply make a conditional style so that I use the `display` toggle only on the silly browsers, and life is great again, but the question remains:

**Is this a bug in Fx/Webkitz, or is it intentional?**

Here's a fiddle for you to look at: http://jsfiddle.net/TheNix/q5bAZ/4/

Comment: toggling the parent element, and setting the transition on the child elements attribute is useful. Also combinations of positioning and visibility can be effective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that transitions happen on computed value changes, and browsers don't compute values for most properties when `display: none` is set.

There is some ... lively discussion about what the spec should say about this.  See the thread starting http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Dec/0353.html and going over the last 4 months or so.

Comment: Interesting stuff! Cheers, Boris. It makes much more sense to me now, even if I don't understand why then it works in Opera. I also can't find any replies later than [December 14 2011](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Dec/0383.html). Are there more? I want to read the thrilling conclusion. :)

Comment: Yeah, there are more.  The silly archives are broken down by month.  If you go to http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/ and look for that subject in later months you can see what more there is of the conversation.  No thrilling conclusion yet!

Comment: not setting `display: none` can be impossible sometimes, as the element will still take some space when only opaque. a solution could be to set `max-height` to zero, and also animate `max-height` (duration: 0s), AND, delay that animation when fading back out.

Comment: also: 2017, problem persists!

Answer (score 0):

Simply omit the `display` declaration and add

```
-moz-opacity: 0.5;
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;
filter: alpha(opacity=x); // x =  0 ... 100.
```

Now with targeting the IEs and other older browsers, you should be fine.

If you want to be extra-accurate you put the filter into an extra IE-stylesheet so you don't invalidate your stylesheet with stupid IE-stuff. ( But with proprietary prefixes only xD )

Comment: That is also one way to do it, but I'm deadly allergic to `filter`. However, I've already supplied a working solution in my question. What I'm looking for, is some theories on why the browsers are behaving like this.